# How to add emotion to telegram markup keyboard

Tags: api, telegram-bot

I create a markup keyboard for my telegram bot, anybody know how I can add emotion in the options look like the below link ?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

salam seyed. the problem is not limit to keyboard. in the message also you have same problem for sending emoji. you must pack the emoji unicode bytes before send:

```
$message .= iconv('UCS-4LE', 'UTF-8', pack('V', 0x1F453));
```

and in [this link](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) you can see the list of emoji code that you need enter in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to perform:

1. copy the emotion from your telegram client;
2. paste it into your IDE as String variable;
3. Use the variable as Inline button's label

[image: capture from telegram client]

Here is a java example:

```java
public InlineKeyboardMarkup getBtn() {
        String label = "\uD83D\uDE04Laughing button";
        String label2 = "\uD83D\uDE21Angry button";

        InlineKeyboardMarkup markup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
        List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();
        List<InlineKeyboardButton> row_1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<InlineKeyboardButton> row_2 = new ArrayList<>();
        row_1.add(new InlineKeyboardButton(label).setCallbackData("1"));
        row_2.add(new InlineKeyboardButton(label2).setCallbackData("2"));
        keyboard.add(row_1);
        keyboard.add(row_2);
        markup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        return markup;
    }
```